# How to change the content of the same HTML element at every item in an ngFor loop (with delay)?

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, delay, ngfor

I'm developing an Angular 6 app (with Bootstrap) and I have created the following template:

```
<div class="news-container">
    <div class="new" *ngFor="let n of news">
        <div class="date">{{n.date}}</div>
        <div class="text">{{n.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to show only one news per time, so every item of the array in the `*ngFor` loop should replace the previous one, and if the loop is at the last item it should restarts from the first item again.

In addition, it would be nice to add a delay between an item and the next one.

Here is how the array looks like:

```
news: [
    {id: 1, date: '01-01-2018', text: 'this is a news'},
    {id: 2, date: '01-01-2018', text: 'this is another news'},
    {id: 3, date: '01-01-2018', text: 'breaking news'},
    {id: 4, date: '01-01-2018', text: 'foo bar'},
]
```

Do you know any solution to reach that?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in this way in the html.  You just need one div and update the model.

Comment: You can create a variable `currentItemIdx` and update it periodically. For example: `setInterval(()=>{this.currentItemIdx = (this.currentItemIdx + 1)%this.news.length;},1000)`

And in the template, remove ngFor and use news[currentItemIdx]

Comment: Very good comment! If you post it as answer I will upvote it! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `setTimeout()` to delay the news items that are displayed and then with a recursive function loop through all the news and start over again. Here is a stackblitz I created with the answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdpkbw

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway I prefer the @Mrigank 's solution.

Comment: His solution doesn’t accommodate looping through the items and starting again, can I at least get an upvote or accept the answer for the effort please? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answer, can't add comment

Why not use $interval to do that? At each interval show an element of the array.

Comment: I said `angular`, not `angularjs` :D

Comment: @smartmouse, my bad, but you could still use some kind of 'interval' to do this